# How to import csv data with parent/child (category-subcategory) hierarchy to MySQL using Python

Tags: python, mysql, mysql-python, hierarchical-data

I am importing a csv file containing a parent/child (category-subcategory) hierarchy to MySQL, using Python's MySQLdb module. Here is an example csv file:

```
vendor,category,subcategory,product_name,product_model,product_price
First vendor,category1,subcategory1,product1,model1,100
First vendor,category1,subcategory2,product2,model2,110
First vendor,category2,subcategory3,product3,model3,130
First vendor,category2,subcategory4,product5,model7,190
```

In MySQL I want to use a `category` table with a hierarchical structure, like this:

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `category` (
`category_id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
`parent_id` int(11) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
`status` tinyint(1) NOT NULL,
PRIMARY KEY (`category_id`),
KEY `parent_id` (`parent_id`)
) ENGINE=MyISAM DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 COLLATE=utf8_general_ci;
```

**My question is:** How do I determine the `parent_id` in this table?

Here is the Python script I have so far:

```
import MySQLdb
import csv
con = MySQLdb.connect('localhost', 'root', '', 'testdb', use_unicode=True, charset='utf8')
with con:
    cur = con.cursor()
    csv_data = csv.reader(file('test.csv'))
    csv_data.next()
    for row in csv_data:
        cur.execute("SELECT manufacturer_id FROM manufacturer WHERE name=%s", [row[0]],)
        res = cur.fetchall()
        if res:
            vendor_id = res[0][0]
        else:
            cur.execute("INSERT INTO manufacturer (name) VALUES (%s)", (row[0],))
            vendor_id = cur.lastrowid
        cur.execute("SELECT category_id FROM category_description WHERE name=%s", [row[2]])
        res = cur.fetchall()
        if res:
            category_id = res[0][0]
        else:

            # What parent_id should be inserted here?
            cur.execute("INSERT INTO category (`status`, `parent_id`) VALUES (%s,%s)", (1,))

            category_id = cur.lastrowid
            cur.execute("INSERT INTO category_description (category_id, name) VALUES (%s,%s)", (category_id,row[2],))
            cur.execute("INSERT INTO product (model, manufacturer_id, price,) VALUES (%s, %s, %s)", (row[4], `vendor_id`, row[8],))                           
            product_id = cur.lastrowid
            cur.execute("INSERT INTO product_to_category (product_id, category_id) VALUES (%s, %s)", (product_id, category_id,))
    cur.commit()
```

Here are the definitions of the other tables used in my example:

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `manufacturer` (
`manufacturer_id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
`name` varchar(64) NOT NULL,
PRIMARY KEY (`manufacturer_id`)
) ENGINE=MyISAM DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 COLLATE=utf8_general_ci;

CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `category_description` (
`category_id` int(11) NOT NULL,
`name` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
PRIMARY KEY (`category_id`,`language_id`),
KEY `name` (`name`)
) ENGINE=MyISAM DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 COLLATE=utf8_general_ci;

CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `product` (
`product_id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
`model` varchar(64) NOT NULL,
`manufacturer_id` int(11) NOT NULL,
`price` decimal(15,4) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0.0000',
PRIMARY KEY (`product_id`)
) ENGINE=MyISAM DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 COLLATE=utf8_general_ci;

CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `product_to_category` (
`product_id` int(11) NOT NULL,
`category_id` int(11) NOT NULL,
PRIMARY KEY (`product_id`,`category_id`),
KEY `category_id` (`category_id`)
) ENGINE=MyISAM DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 COLLATE=utf8_general_ci;
```

Comment: Is your hierarchy fixed-depth with two levels, or is it possible for the category that appears in one row of the CSV file to also appear as the subcategory in another row (and vice versa)?

Comment: Yes, hierarchy fixed-depth with two levels.

Comment: I think in case If category that appears in one row of the CSV file to also appear as the subcategory in another row I need to rename that category or subcategory with for example row[1] = row[1].replace('category_with_name_like_subcategory_name','unique_category_name')

Comment: I found what was a problem:simply not correct row index for inserting as parent category.

Answer (score 0):

In a hierarchical table structure, any member at the top of its hierarchy has no parents. I would probably show this with a `NULL` parent ID but based on the way you've defined your `category` table, it looks like you want to show this by giving the value `0` for the parent ID.

Since you have fixed-depth hierarchies with only two levels (category and subcategory), the task is relatively simple. For each row of the CSV data, you need to:

1. Check whether the parent (`row[1]`) is in the table; if not, insert it with a parent ID of `0`.
2. Get the `category_id` of the parent from step 1.
3. Check whether the child (`row[2]`) is in the table; if not, insert it with a parent ID equal to the `category_id` from step 2.

In your example code, you never access the parent (`row[1]`); you need to insert this into the table for it to have an ID that the child can refer to. If you've already inserted the parents before this point, you should probably still check to make sure it's there.

You have some other problems here:

1. The PK of your `category_description` table is defined on a column that you forgot to define in the table (`language_id`).
2. You should really be using InnoDB in this physical model so that you can enforce foreign key constraints in `category_description`, `product` and `product_to_category`.
3. In your example, `cur.commit()` is going to throw an exception – that's a method of the `Connection` object in MySQLdb. Of course, `COMMIT` isn't implemented for MyISAM tables anyway, so you could also avoid the exception by removing the line entirely.
4. Referencing `row[8]` is also going to throw an exception, according to the CSV data you've shown us. (This is a good example of why you should test your MCVE to make sure it works!)
5. If you do switch to InnoDB – and you probably should – you can use `with con as cur:` to get a cursor that commits itself when you exit the `with` block. This saves a couple lines of code and lets you manage transactions without micromanaging the connection object.

Comment: Could You advise how import csv next time without truncate table if some categories or subcategories deleted in csv? Delete from?

Comment: Your question is unclear. If you need to import another CSV file into the same tables, you should be able to do it the same way.

Comment: Yes, import another CSV file into the same tables. But another CSV file with new categories and subcategories. During inserting in mysql - how to delete old categories?

Comment: There is no need to delete the old categories. You can store any number of different hierarchies in the table, as long as the category names are unique. If they are not, you either need separate tables or a hierarchy identifier in the table.